# How to retrieve a txt file from raw.githubusercontent.com and find and replace characters?

Tags: javascript, text

For a miscellaneous project, I need to use a long text file (containing lots of words), separated by newlines, (`\n`) and I've tried to replace all the newlines with spaces. I've tried to use not only online tools as well as Vim, Subline, and Atom to find-and-replace, but they all froze (except for Vim, there was no replace). Just note, my text file contains over 370000 words.

I'm thinking about retrieving this text file (located at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt) with a JS script, but I have no idea how to 1: Retrieve the file, 2: Put it into a variable (or something), 3: Find and replace \n with  (space character), and 4: Get that file.

Comment: what have to tried while solving it with JS? show us the code

Comment: VIM supports search and replace: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Comment: I don't know where to start as I can't make a variable with more that 370000 words, and I don't know how to retrieve a txt file.

Comment: I actually used Vim and the _same webpage_, and it provided no help. I'm on mac, if that helps.

Comment: Actually I'm on Chrome OS, at school. No download software or anything :(

Comment: "I don't know how to retrieve a txt file" there are plenty tutorials out there that show you how to do it. you have to put in more work on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you'r looking for something along the lines of this, if you'd like to learn more about **how** I got the data, then take a look at the [`fetch` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). To have converted the data to a string, I simply used the `text` function which you can find more documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text).

Finally I then simply replaced all of the `\n` chars with a regular space, if you'd like to learn more about the replace method, you can read more into it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt';

fetch(url).then(d => d.text()).then(d => console.log(d.replace(/\n/g, ' ')));
```

Comment: Um, but I don't really understand what that is doing. Fetch(url) gets the content, then .then(d => d.text())? I don't get the second part.

Comment: That's why I provided links to documentation, but in basic terms, fetch gets the data, `then` it gets all of the `text` from the data that was fetched, finally it `then` replaces all `\n` with a blank space. It's pretty much as simple as that.

Comment: Does that make a bit more sense not @EthanSlota?

Comment: It does greatly! Also, don't do this: copy and paste the output into the Chrome search bar; it crashed my computer (a first in my entire life)

Comment: @EthanSlota I can't say I'm totally amazed by that, as awesome as Chrome is, I'm pretty sure the search bar is **not** designed to handle that amount of data, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use JS for that.
You can do entire operation in Bash or Powershell, using built-in tools.

For Windows there is good text editor named [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/)
You can open file, press `CTRL + A`, `Edit > Line Operations > Join Lines`